# My replace function works with array but not with HTML collection which is also an array. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am writting a function to replace the position of some HTML elements in the page. Should be simple and it goes like this :

```
let square = document.getElementById("SquareCharts").children;
let testArray = ["A", "b", "c", "d", "E", "f", "g"];

function Replace(arr, oldPosition, newPosition)
{
    let store;

    store = arr[newPosition];
    arr[newPosition] = arr[oldPosition];
    arr[oldPosition] = store;

    return console.log(arr);
}

replace(testArray, 4, 0);
replace(square, 4, 0);
```

It works with testArray but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the HTML elements order. Why and what can I do to change the original DOM?

Comment: Changing the `children` elements will not change the original DOM I guess.

Comment: What can I do to change the DOM ?

Comment: append them back after change ?

Comment: Ok , I have to use those appendChild and createElement things. Thanks, I will study it..

Comment: [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) is not an array, it's an intrinsic object. Notice also, that the collection returned by `children` is live, it reflects the changes made to the DOM. It's not said anywhere, but understandably, a live collection is a read-only for JS:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear the element's current children then append them again.

```js
let square = document.getElementById("SquareCharts").children;
let testArray = ["A", "b", "c", "d", "E", "f", "g"];

function Replace(arr, oldPosition, newPosition)
{
    let store;

    store = arr[newPosition];
    arr[newPosition] = arr[oldPosition];
    arr[oldPosition] = store;

    // clear children
    square.innerHTML = '';
    for(const element of arr) {
        square.append(element);
    }

    return console.log(arr);
}

replace(testArray, 4, 0);
replace(square, 4, 0);
```

`document.getElementById("SquareCharts").children` returns a `HTMLCollection`. Although it is iterable using a for-loop, it is **not** an Array.

You can also do:

```
let square = Array.from(document.getElementById("SquareCharts").children);
```

so that you can get more functionality with `Array`'s built-in methods.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @izzypt, If the answer helped you, then take this answer as a solved.